# Remove duplicate json when creating hmtl from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm trying to populate a div dynamically with data from JSON but want to avoid duplicates. The script below will give me 3 divs, 2 "standard" and one "special".

How can I achieve without creating duplicate div?

```
var productList = [ 
   { 
        model:"helskap",
        type:"special",
        family:"Bravo"
   },
   { 
        model:"Z-skap",
        type:"standard",
        family:"Valhalla"
    },
    { 
        model:"smafacksskap",
        type:"standard",
        family:"Jona"
   }

];
```

```
$.each(productList, function(i, item) {     
    $('.filter').append('<div class="' + productList[i].type+ '"><input type="radio" name="type" value="' + productList[i].type+ '" /><label>' + productList[i].type+ '</label></div>')
});
```

```
<div class"filter"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better way is to first get the array with unique objects on property `type` then you can use that new filtered array for rendering like in `filterProductList`:

```js
var productList = [{
    model: "helskap",
    type: "special",
    family: "Bravo"
  },
  {
    model: "Z-skap",
    type: "standard",
    family: "Valhalla"
  },
  {
    model: "smafacksskap",
    type: "standard",
    family: "Jona"
  }

];

var filterProductList = productList.reduce((acc, item) => {
  var existItem = acc.find(({type}) => type === item.type);
  if (!existItem) {
    acc.push(item);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(filterProductList);
```

Then use `filterProductList` to render the HTML in your page. Your code will look:

```
$.each(filterProductList, function(i, item) {  
  var type = filterProductList[i].type;
  $('.filter').append('<div class="' + type + '"><input type="radio" name="type" value="' + type + '" /><label>' + type + '</label></div>')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easy way is to create each `div` with `id="type"`, then append contents to `div id="type"`.

Comment: Id's should be unique, you should be using a class for this method instead.